# spin images as ring in visual basic

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, image, visual-studio

I wonder is there any way to spin images in visual basic like a ring? I would like to create a windows form application that takes images from directory and spins them in a window.

ex: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ring.jsf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called Carousel Control. Here is a [free implementation on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/283025/Simple-Carousel-Control-for-Windows-Forms).

Also see this: [How can I create a custom 3D carousel control in WinForms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908333/how-can-i-create-a-custom-3d-carousel-control-in-winforms)

There are paid controls out there, just do a google search for `carousel control for winforms`.

Answer (score 0):

WPF was made for that. You have the ability to transform any control or shape and animate with Storyboards for smooth transitions they rotate.